# TSQL: Returned value of a function is the name of the column

Tags: sql, t-sql, function, variables

I have a function which using several cases to look up the current period returns a varchar(50) which is the period column necessary for what I need.

I would like to do a SUM of this column, and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Example:

```
Select SUM(ABS([dbo].[ACTUAL_PERIOD] ())) FROM Finance_DB
```

Any help would be great.

Also, do you think I should bother using the function in the first place? Basically all it does is work through 12 case statements that determines what period we are in by looking up another table. At first I was going to use a stored procedure, but duh...it won't return anything. The reason why I was going to use it was because this particular case statement appears repetitively throughout the entire query and all others. It gets long and I thought a procedure/function would look neater. However, having done some reading online, I understand that certain circumstances don't actually benefit from having functions as opposed to writing the query inline, how ever verbose it might be. Any thoughts?

Comment: Though it is implied that this is SQL Server, please add it in the tags.

Comment: Can you post the code for your current function and how it is being used? And what exactly doesn't work that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to sum varchar values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should use a dynamic SQL. 
For example:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(100);
select @SQL='Select SUM(ABS('+[dbo].[ACTUAL_PERIOD]()+')) FROM Finance_DB';
execute sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, though I was trying to avoid going dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly you got period values in different columns.

```
 Period1 Period2 Period3...   
   100      200     400
   130      250     300
```

Use unpivot to convert columns to rows so it looks like

```
ColumnName Value
Period1    100
Period2    200
Period3    400
...
```

The code will look something like

```
WITH Values AS (
    SELECT ColumnName
          ,Value
    FROM Finance_DB
         UNPIVOT (Value FROM ColumnName IN (Period1, Period2,...)
)
SELECT SUM(ABS(Value))
FROM Values
WHERE ColumnName = Actual_Period();
```